# Memory usage in a Rails app, how to monitor and troubleshoot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory-management

I have a Rails app that among other things, have several background jobs which are computationally expensive (image manipulation :O).

I am using Sidekiq to manage those jobs. I currently have set a concurrency of 5 threads per Sidekiq process and here is what I do in order to see the memory usage:

```
ps faux | grep sidekiq
```

Results are this:

```
hommerzi    3874  3.5  5.7 287484 231756 pts/5   Sl+  17:17   0:10  |   \_ sidekiq 2.17.0 imageparzer [3 of 3 busy]
```

However, I have a feeling that there must be a way to monitor this correctly from within the Rails app, or am I wrong?

My question would be: How can I monitor my memory usage in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to use Monit (or God) to manage your processes. This goes for database, server, application; not just background jobs.

Here's an example: [Monit Ruby on Rails Sidekiq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433866/monit-ruby-on-rails-sidekiq)

Monitor your application for a while and set realistic memory limits. Then, if one of your processes dies or goes above that limit for a given amount of cycles (usually 2 minute checks), it will (re)start the process.

You can also setup an alert email address and a web frontend (with basic HTTP auth). This will prove essential for running stable applications in production. For example, recently I had a sidekiq process get carried away with itself and chew up 250mb memory. Monit then restarted the process (which is now hovering around 150mb) and sent me an alert. Now I can check the logs/system to see why that might have happened. This all happened while I was asleep. Much better than the alternative: waking up and finding your server on its knees with a runaway process or downed service.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-configure-monit