# Monit not starting process - Execution Failed Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monitoring, sidekiq, monit

I am using monit gem to monitor my sidekiq process
My Monitrc config file:-

```
check process sidekiq_process with pidfile /home/path_to_pid
start program = "bundle exec sidekiq -d -L log/sidekiq.log -C config/sidekiq.yml -e development"  with timeout 60 seconds
stop program  = "bundle exec sidekiq -d -L log/sidekiq.log -C config/sidekiq.yml -e development"
```

My sidekiq.yml file:-

```
 development:
:pidfile: tmp/pids/sidekiq_development.pid
:logfile: log/sidekiq_development.log
:concurrency: 1
```

After running sidekiq using `bundle exec sidekiq -d -L log/sidekiq.log -C config/sidekiq.yml -e development` and then running `sudo monit`, `sudo monit status` gives me this:-

```
Process 'sidekiq_process'
status                            Running
monitoring status                 Monitored
pid                               10951
parent pid                        1378
uid                               1000
effective uid                     1000
gid                               1000
uptime                            0m 
threads                           2
children                          0
memory                            103.4 MB
memory total                      103.4 MB
memory percent                    1.3%
memory percent total              1.3%
cpu percent                       0.0%
cpu percent total                 0.0%
data collected                    Mon, 13 Aug 2018 12:14:06
```

So, it is monitoring fine, it even sends me mail "Does not exist" when I kill the sidekiq process, but the problem is after sidekiq process is killed, it should also restart the process. Here is what `sudo monit status` gives me after sidekiq is killed

```
Process 'sidekiq_process'
status                            Execution failed
monitoring status                 Monitored
data collected                    Mon, 13 Aug 2018 12:19:13
```

I also get mail stating "Execution Failed".
Why am I getting execution failed error and why process is not being restarted by monit?

Comment: when the process is killed, can you confirm if the pid in the file is deleted `tmp/pids/sidekiq_development.pid` ?

Comment: No, the file is not removed, it still contains pid (in this case- 10951), although I do get the mail "monit alert- Does not exist Service sidekiq_process"

Comment: I have not used Monit myself, can you take a look at [read_the_last_comment](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/3679) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433866/monit-ruby-on-rails-sidekiq)

Answer (score 1):

wrap your exec command in a shell script and chmod +x it, and check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51839285/7266232)

Comment: I have decided to use eye gem instead